Performance counter not running with perf_event_open()
I am trying to access the performance counters in a large and complex application. But when I read the result it always returns 0. I also enabled the total running time and the total enabled time, which both return 0. The code I use for this is listed below:
  perf_event_attr PerfEvent;
  std::memset(&PerfEvent, 0, sizeof(PerfEvent));
  PerfEvent.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
  PerfEvent.disabled = 0;
  PerfEvent.pinned = 1;
  PerfEvent.inherit = 1;
  PerfEvent.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
  PerfEvent.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_TOTAL_TIME_ENABLED | PERF_FORMAT_TOTAL_TIME_RUNNING;

  int fd = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &PerfEvent, getpid(), -1, -1, 0);
  
  // Code to profile
  
  uint64_t RetVal[3];
  const int32_t rc = read(fd, &RetVal, sizeof(RetVal));
  close(fd);

I also ensured that the application has the following capabilities: CAP_PERFMON and CAP_SYS_ADMIN. I even wrote a little function to check this in the application itself.
const bool IsCapabilitySet(int Capability){
  if(!cap_valid(Capability)){
    std::cout << "ERROR: Capability is not valid\n";
    return false;
  }

  return (prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, Capability) == 1);
}

On top of that /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid is set to 0.
When I use the code above in a very simple application on the same system, it returns correct performance counters.
How could I solve this problem, and where can I find the code that updates these performance counters in the Linux codebase?

Please try the standard perf utility to read at least some counters and see if it's succesful.
Other than that if you use a virtualization software, see if PMU virtualization is enabled in the hypervisor.

Perf works fine, the code itself also works fine. I ran the code in a smaller much smaller application(just a main with a loop), and this worked fine for me.
